# Saving List to XMLFile

Tags: java, xml

I would like to save my `ArrayList` to an `XML` File. Actually I tried it but I just saved a whole object of list without any `<>`. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2f7H.jpg) and I wish it looked like

```
<title>XYZ</title>
<description>XYZ</description>
```

This is what I have already tried:

```
public class Book {

    public String title;
    public String author;
    public double price;
    public String description;

    public static ArrayList<String> entires = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title=title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author){
        this.author=author;
    }


    public void setPrice(double price){
        this.price=price;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return title+"\n"+author+"\n"+description+"\n"+"Price: "+price+"$"+"\n";
    }

}
```

and:

```
 public class FileOperations {

    private Book book = new Book();

    public void saveList() throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("books.xml");
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        XMLEncoder xmlEncoder = new XMLEncoder(bufferedOutputStream);
        xmlEncoder.writeObject(book.entires);
        xmlEncoder.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try writing to xml using DOM http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/

Comment: I couldn't help myself but the same guy did a nice little tutorial on using jaxb.  So I am not sure exactly what you are doing but take a look at jaxb http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/.